# Call and store data from a API in React Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am particularly noob to react. Iam trying to call a API and save its data in a React reducer with Axios, but somehow the API call is not working as expected.

But while hard-coding the same output of the API in the reducer, everything works like a charm. Please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong.
Did I call the API correctly?

Here the Reducer with the Axios API call and just below is the response as hard coded:

```
export default function() {

  return function (dispatch) {

    axios.get("http://localhost/getUserDetails")
    .then(
      (response) => {

        dispatch({
          type: GET_USER_ROLES,
          data: (
            response.data
          )
        })

      }
    )
  }
}

{/* this below function when uncomment works totally fine
export default function() {
  return {
  "ldap": "user",
  "name": "user",
  "role": "ABC,XYZ"
}
}*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code from my sample project. Once you make the call, please write to the console.log to view the output received from API. Also, open the **Dev Tools** -> **Network Tab** to view whether the API call was successful or not.

```
export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

        dispatch({
            type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
            payload: {
                product: data._id,
                name: data.name,
                image: data.image,
                price: data.price,
                countInStock: data.countInStock,
                qty
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: null,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message
                : error.message
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Viswanatha :). I will give it a try and share the feedback